# How to update a database that has foreign keys constraints?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have one virtual machine (VM_A) that runs one mysql database DB_A schema with 200 rows in his tbl_1. In another virtual machine (VM_B) that runs a copy of the same DB_A schema I have 50 rows in the tbl_1.

I would like to update the DB_B with the data from DB_A.

The tbl_2 holds a foreign key from tbl_1.

I've already made a mysql dump from DB_A to run in DB_B, to be updated.

I do not want to use drop schema, before drop tbl_1.

If I try to run the code in DB_B I will have a error caused by foreign key constarint in tbl_2.

What could be the best approach to update the DB_B in this scenario?
I have already tested this solution but not worked https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40046/is-there-a-way-to-truncate-table-that-has-foreign-a-key

Comment: the link that you posted pertains to sql server not necessarily will that work on mysql...

Comment: mysql replication perhaps? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: i've tried to use the same idea, only.

Comment: how could replication works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40046/is-there-a-way-to-truncate-table-that-has-foreign-a-key is ms sql-server. in mysql modify your session variables

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```